# Vector of structs inside of vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Imagine something like account database of social network in C++. Each account has it's username, level (admin, etc.), list of users who follow this account and list of users who messaged this account.

Problem is, I wanna count number of messages received by each separate user, so name and count in inner struct gotta be linked together.

Is this good idea of implementation?

```
    struct User {
        string name;
        int level;

        vector<string> followedBy;
        struct MessagedBy {
            string name;
            int count;
        };
    };

vector<User> users;
//@TODO vector of MessagedBy as an instance of User
```

How do I create *vector of structs* inside of *vector of structs*? How do I point at it?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using structs and not classes?

Comment: @wittybear structs are classes.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if I use structs or classes, both are okay with me.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to permit people to change their names. How about using an additional `int id` to identify a user and to refer to them in `MessagedBy` and `followedBy`?

Comment: Yes, that is a great tip, Christian. This software is actually supposed to translate user entry to GraphViz syntax, so I guess I won't need that this time. ;)

Comment: @"R. Martinho Fernandes" of course you are correct, I was just trying to encourage "good practise"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you would probably want something like this:

```
struct User {
        string name;
        int level;

    vector<string> followedBy;
    struct MessagedBy {
        string name;
        int count;
    };
    vector<MessageBy> messages;
};
```

You can then use:

```
cout << "Messages from: " << users[index].messages[otherindex].name << ":" << users[index].messages[otherindex].count;
```

Comment: I did include that in my answer... `vector<MessageBy> messages;`